# GET 500 (internal error) PHP

Tags: php, php-7

Bom dia,

Escrevi uma classe PHP

```
<?php 

private $v;
private $v2;
private $v3;

public function __construct(){
    printf("Objeto criado com sucesso!");
}

public function setValor(){
    $this->$v = "valor";
    $this->$v2 = "valor2";
    $this->$v3 = "valor3";
}

public function getValor1(){
    return $this->$v;
}

public function getValor2(){
    return $this->$v2;
}

public function getValor3(){
    return $this->$v3;
}
}
$t = new Teste();
$t->setValor();
?>
```

Mas não consigo acessar o método serValor(), recebo sempre o erro GET 500 (internal Server Error), entretanto não vejo nada de errado no código, alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Acho estranho ser só nesse método: experimenta: `$this->v = "valor";` sem os "$" em todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando for acessar as variáveis, não precisa utilizar mais o cifrão `$`.

```
public function setValor(){
    $this->v = "valor";
    $this->v2 = "valor2";
    $this->v3 = "valor3";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolvi XD!

Comment: Reverti a [edição 3](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/192658/revisions), pois não se trata nem do que o autor da pergunta aceitou, nem intenção do Henrique. Se alguém tem uma resposta diferente da atual, basta postar em separado (e é super bem-vindo a colaborar, afinal o formato do site é de uma pergunta e várias respostas, e isto é incentivado). Se a nova resposta for melhor o autor da pergunta pode alterar a aceitação a qualquer momento. Aproveitar accept alheio abre precedentes duvidosos, por melhor que seja a intenção e impede a comunidade de votar separado em cada colaborador.